Input string is "My Name is Khan" and Output is "Kh anis Na meMy"
"How to convert String to out sprint."
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverseString("My Name is Khan");
    }
    
    public static String reverseString(String input)
    {
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        String reveseString = "";
        for(int i=words.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            reveseString = words[i]+" ";
            System.out.print(reveseString);
        }
        
        return reveseString;
    }
}

Output is "Khan is Name My"
I want output is "Kh anis Na meMy"

To help you get started, remember that you can get the length of an existing string using stringName .length().

You need to explain what your requirement is. What would the output be for "My Monicker is Jim"?

please describe all the steps need to get that output, as detailed as possible, otherwise we could write if (input.equals("My Name is Khan")) System.out.println("Kh anis Na meMy"); which most probably is not exactly what you want. || BTW are you sure you want "Kh anis Na meMy" and not "Khan is Name My"? (first is not that trivial, not usually seen/used)

I have a solution for you. For those of you who don't get the requirement, it seems the problem is to reverse the order of the words, BUT the position of the spaces in the original string must be preserved. My solution breaks down this problem and provides methods for each individual step in the process.

@tgdavies the output would be "Ji misMonic ke rMy". Reverse the words, relocate the spaces to their original location.

@hfontanez if you didn't get it, having the OP describing the steps would help them to code it and learn from doing so... providing code  will most probably not help their learning :-( (and providing code is not really the intention of StackOverflow)

@user85421 Stating that I just gave the OP the code is not accurate in the least. I did way more than that. I explained the problem, gave the recipe on how to build the solution, and then showed the implementation. This is 100% within the guidelines of Stack Overflow. IN FACT, providing "no code answers" while not in the bylaws, is looked upon negatively by the community and downvoted to no end more times than none. I provided an implementation because the OP showed some level of effort. His solution was partial. I just completed it.

Here is one way.
String s = "My Name is Khan";
System.out.println(reverseString(s));

prints
Kh anis Na meMy


first, split the string into words using one or more spaces as a delimiter and store in an array. \\s+ is a regular expression for one or more spaces.
then copy those words in reverse order to an instance of StringBuilder.
Note if you just want the words in reverse order, the String can be returned at this point using StringBuilder.toString(). Otherwise, proceed to insert the spaces.
then iterate over the original string, and find the indices of each space and insert them in that location in StringBuilder.
then return the new string.


public static String reverseString(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(words[i]);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while ((i = input.indexOf(' ', i)) >= 0) {
        sb.insert(i++, ' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}



"My Name is Khan" (original)
"Kh anis Na meMy" (expected)

It seems you are trying to reverse the "words" but preserving the spaces at their current location. So basically, you could do something like this:

Map out (list) the current indexes of all spaces: 2, 7, 10. Save these in an array (let's call it nextSpace).
Create functions to 1) Reverse the order of words, 2) Clear spaces in the string (to be reinserted later), 3) Insert spaces at a specific location (restore spaces).

public class ReverseStringTokens {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalString = "My Name is Khan";
        String expectedString = "Kh anis Na meMy";
        
        System.out.println(originalString);

        List<Integer> spaces = createSpaceIndexList(originalString);

        String reversed = reversedWords(originalString);
        System.out.println(reversed);

        String cleared = clearSpaces(reversed);
        System.out.println(cleared);

        String actualOutput = insertSpaces(cleared, spaces);
        System.out.println("Actual output equals expected output = " + expectedString.equals(actualOutput));

    }

    public static List<Integer> createSpaceIndexList(String temp) {
        char character = ' ';
        List<Integer> nextSpace = IntStream.range(0, temp.length())
                .filter(i -> temp.charAt(i) == character).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return nextSpace;
    }

    public static String reversedWords (String input) {
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            output.append(words[i]);
            output.append(" ");
        }

        return output.toString().trim();
    }

    public static String clearSpaces(String input) {
        return input.replaceAll(" ", "");
    }

    public static String insertSpaces(String input, List<Integer> spaces) {
        int startIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < spaces.size(); i++) {
            int endIdx = spaces.get(i);
            input = input.substring(0, endIdx) + " " + input.substring(endIdx);
        }
        System.out.println(input);
        return input;
    }

}

The output of this program is:
My Name is Khan
Khan is Name My
KhanisNameMy
Kh anis Na meMy
Actual output equals expected output = true

The function to clear the spaces and the one that reinserts the spaces could be combined into one. However, I believe in separating these two actions for reusability.
